# What is the non-deprecated way to display a stock icon in GTK3?

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I'm assembling a GUI using PyGObject.  This Python code works in context.  I get a toolbar button with the stock "Open" icon.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

# ...

toolbar = Gtk.Toolbar()
toolbar.get_style_context().add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)

# ...

self.fileOpen = Gtk.ToolButton.new_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_OPEN)
self.fileOpen.connect("clicked", self.on_FileOpenStandard_activate)
toolbar.insert(self.fileOpen, -1)
```

[image: Image shows icon appearing on the toolbar.]

But according to [this resource](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/ToolButton.html#Gtk.ToolButton.new_from_stock), `new_from_stock()` is deprecated:

> **Deprecated since version 3.10:** Use `Gtk.ToolButton.new ()` together with `Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name ()` instead.

Okay then.  So after digging further, this is what I came up with for a replacement:

```
self.fileOpen = Gtk.ToolButton(
        Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name("document-open",
                                     Gtk.IconSize.LARGE_TOOLBAR),
        "Open")
self.fileOpen.connect("clicked", self.on_FileOpenStandard_activate)
toolbar.insert(self.fileOpen, -1)
```

But this is the result:

[image: Image shows icon not appearing on the toolbar.]

What is the correct way to do this that is still supported by the current GTK library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at this [C++ GitHub example](https://github.com/gtk-rs/examples/blob/master/src/text_viewer.rs), I'm surprised to discover a direct call to the static `new()` function rather than the constructor.

So I decided to try it.  Look carefully at the difference.  It's subtle.

```
                              #vvv
self.fileOpen = Gtk.ToolButton.new(
        Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name("document-open",
                                     Gtk.IconSize.LARGE_TOOLBAR),
        "Open")
self.fileOpen.connect("clicked", self.on_FileOpenStandard_activate)
toolbar.insert(self.fileOpen, -1)
```

To my surprise, this displays the icon where the other approach does not.

**Bonus:** Cleaner version of the above:

```
# iconSize to be reused
iconSize = Gtk.IconSize.LARGE_TOOLBAR

# ...

openIcon = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name("document-open", iconSize)
self.fileOpen = Gtk.ToolButton.new(openIcon, "Open")
self.fileOpen.connect("clicked", self.on_FileOpenStandard_activate)
toolbar.insert(self.fileOpen, -1)
```

Comment: The explanation for what you found: in the PyGObject bindings, objects' constructors only take keyword args representing the object's GObject properties. On the other hand, C constructors, which often have extra convenience parameters to set properties since properties can be cumbersome in C, are bound as static `new()` methods.This should work equally well: `Gtk.ToolButton(icon_widget=openIcon, label="Open")`